# Where did load balancing using FreeBSD CARP go?

Tags: load-balancing, freebsd, carp

In some old manuals I see `net.inet.carp.arpbalance` sysctl, that turns on load balancing between CARP'ed interfaces. Recent manuals (FreeBSD 10+) say nothing about it.

Where did that feature go and what was the reason for it?

Comment: if you don't get an answer here,  try the Unix exchange or email bsdnow at juniper broadcasting,  they usually know what's up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature was removed in FreeBSD 10, see commit https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=228571 . The carp system was basically rewritten from scratch. As for "why", I can only guess that it did not seem an important feature at the time of rewriting.